Find all possible values of a parallel vector with equal magnitude
Consider the vectors $u = ai - bj + ck$ and $v = i -8j + 4k$.
Find all possible values of $a, b$ and $c$ if $u$ is parallel to $v$ and has a magnitude of 3.
I tried doing $a=λ, b=8λ$, and $c=4λ$.
Then i got $a^2+b^2+c^2=9$, so $81λ^2=9$, giving me $λ=±\frac{1}{3}$
I am unsure of what to do from here.

I think you have pretty much answered the question: $a=\frac{-1}{3},b=\frac{8}{3},c=\frac{-4}{3}$ or  $a=\frac{1}{3},b=\frac{-8}{3},c=\frac{4}{3}$

Thanks for the advice, I overlooked that. Write an answer so I can mark it as the correct solution.

Since $u$ and $v$ are parallel vectors, we can write $v=t\times u$ for some scalar $t$.
So we have $ai-bj+ck=ti-8tj+4tk$.
Equating components gives $a=t,b=8t,c=4t$.
Since the length of $u$ is 3, we can write $a^2+b^2+c^2=3^2$
Which, in turn means $t^2+64t^2+16t^2=9$ and therefore $t=\frac{-1}{3}$ or $t=\frac{1}{3}$.
If $t=\frac{-1}{3}$, we have $u=\frac{1}{3}i-\frac{8}{3}j+\frac{4}{3}k$
If $t=\frac{-1}{3}$, we have $u=\frac{-1}{3}i+\frac{8}{3}j-\frac{4}{3}k$
Since these vectors are parallel but opposite in direction, they will be the only vectors parallel to $v$ with magnitude 3.

Well, if two vectors are parallel their cross product is zero.
There should only be one possible set of values for a vector with a fixed magnitude in 3 dimensions to be parallel to another one unless you are also considering antiparallel (imagine a fixed direction and rotating an arrow of fixed size).
For the given vector $u$ to have magnitude 3 yes, $a^2+b^2+c^2=9$, and there must be some common factor between the components of $u$ and $v$, but we also have the cross product at our disposal.
$u\times v=0$
This means
$$u \times v=0
$$
$$(-4b+8c)=0$$
$$(c-4a)=0$$
$$(-8a+b)=0$$
This is now a system of equations that can be solved for all three coefficients. 
